# Is time still (frozen) for a single isolated particle?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, time, arrow-of-time

I understand entropy is called the arrow of time because it is the only physical property which always increases in an isolated system (based on 2nd law of thermodynamics).

On the other hand, entropy is the degree of disorder of a system. When we talk about order/disorder, we are talking about a group of particles and their state relative to each other.

Does it mean for a single particle which is isolated (far away in vacuum space) time is still? Is it rational to suppose a particle in such state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly imagine such a Universe with one lonely structureless and cold particle, interacting with nothing and living in some eternal and unchanging spacetime. Of course such a Universe it is nothing like our own. My answer would be that since nothing ever changes in this Universe, there is not really an operational notion of time.

We can imagine this is a massive quantum particle living in Minkowski space; then there is at least a frequency associated with the Compton wavelength of the particle (in its rest frame), which would put a physical clock in the Universe. But there would be no arrow of time

Such a Universe is so weird that it borders on not being mainstream physics. But I can see its value as a thought experiment as in your question to clarify that, indeed, to measure time there need to be something changing, and to have an arrow of time there needs to be irreversibility -- in our Universe, this emerges through the second law because entropy was lower in the early Universe, and (on average) increases toward the future.

Comment: Good answer ! A single-particle universe has only state so only one value for entropy so it is simultaneously in its state of minimum and maximum entropy i.e. it has its Big Bang and its Heat Death at the same "time".

Comment: Ok. But you should be careful not to give the OP the impression that time is a *consequence* of "the arrow of time" (by what he seems to mean the 2nd principle of thermodynamics), which seems to be what he believes and is wrong.

Comment: @Yvan Velenik could you please elaborate what you mean by time is not a consequence of entropy increase? Is time a separate entity which is just related to entropy?

Comment: @YvanVelenik The perceptual past must be in the direction of decreasing entropy in order to allow the formation of reliable memories and records. In this sense, the perceptual arrow of time and the thermodynamic arrow of time are interlinked.

Comment: @gandalf61 Possibly. However, time exists even if it is not perceived. I did not understand his question as being about *perceived* time, but actual time.

Comment: In mainstream physics theories, time (and space) have independent existence. Then, the arrow of time is a consequence of dynamics, statistics and very special initial conditions in the distant past.

Comment: If there's just one particle, could we also say there's no position, distance, velocity, etc.? These are all based on comparing particles to each other, so what would you be comparing?

Comment: @YvanVelenik I would say if there is no operational way you *could* measure time, or a direction of time, in a given Universe, even in principle, then there is no real physical meaning to time in that Universe. Keep in mind this Universe doesn't have any observers, clocks, or anything that varies with time.

Comment: @Andrew This is a site about physics. The existence of an observer is not an assumption made in any theory I am aware of. Our theories presuppose the existence of a suitable space-time and then predict evolution of systems (of course, this is a slight oversimplification, as the space-time structure can be part of the dynamical variables). They predict, under suitable assumptions, that systems evolve in the way postulated by the second principle (up to minor subtleties).

Comment: @YvanVelenik We have to agree to disagree. Like I said in my answer, I feel this model is bordering on non-mainstream physics because it's so weird. But in terms of *physics*, I strongly believe that a quantity introduced in a formalism, that has no observable consequences, is not a physical quantity. For example: the numerical values of the vector potential in electromagnetism are not observable even in principle, and so do not have a *physical* meaning (even though they are useful as intermediate steps in a calculation).

Comment: As an example: your philosophy of presupposing a fixed spacetime in which we do calculations doesn't really work in GR, but even if we adapt this to be a dynamical spacetime, it may well be that in a complete quantum theory of gravity (once it is known) we don't follow the procedure outlined in your comment. I am open minded as to whether space and time are necessary elements of a physical theory, but my mind is firmly made up that for a quantity to be physical, there must be (at least an in-principle) way to measure it.